# Ajax response with numerical 0 gets parsed into undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm running an Ajax call with jQuery that returns an object with a field that is 0 (numerical zero). However, the data returned by jQuery has that field to set to 'undefined'.

Sample code

```
$.ajax({
   url: myUrl
}).done(descriptions => {
   console.debug(descriptions)
})
```

The data returned by the server has the correct value, I verified this in Firefox dev tools and via a raw curl request:

> {"type":0,"medium":0,"text":"Some text"}

The output of the console.debug call shows the values of the fields "type" and "medium" as 'undefined'

When the fields "type" or "medium" are 1 or 2, the values are parsed correctly. Why is the zero (0) value changed to undefined and how can I prevent this?

Comment: It seems like it's your backend's serialisation. I sincerely doubt it is jQuery doing this. You can verify the data that comes in by opening the dev tools and checking the network tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @VLAZ, I did check the network tab and confirmed that a numeric zero (0) is returned by the backend.

Comment: Do you have any global config for jQuery that adds cusom parsing of JSON or anything to that effect?

Comment: No, the only global configuration for jQuery we added was setting authentication headers for all requests using $.ajaxSetup

Comment: What is your version of jQuery? I'll try to test that.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/8fudb1w0/).

Comment: Is this the exact request than in your code? I suppose not, but do you still have the same problem when using this exact sample in your code?

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Comment: The request is not exactly the same: I removed a lot of fields that are redundant to this question.

Comment: At first I thought it was a representation problem with Firefox, but the following if condition fails: if (description.medium === 0 && description.title === 0) {

Answer (score -1):

When sending the request, add the dataType property. Jquery does automatic parsing of the return data if this is omitted and can break the result. They call this `Intelligent Guessing` and from their [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it works like this:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are: ...

Since your server returns JSON, make sure you tell that to jQuery in order to avoid issues like the one you are experiencing. Your call should look like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: myUrl,
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(descriptions => {
   console.debug(descriptions)
})
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue unfortunately. I had thought of that but the server also returns a content-type so I was relatively sure that wouldn't solve it.

Comment: I proposed a solution that has proven valid tons of times so far and I get -1 in return :) Thank you!

Comment: You have to realize that an answer needs to answer the actual question, not only to be valuable for a general case. For this situation, the JSON is properly decoded as a JS object, but has wrong values. So this doesn't answer the question (note: downvote not mine)

Comment: I didn't post it because it is valuable, but because I have solved the same exact issue previously. jQuery's Intelligent guessing is a two-edged sword and leads to issues like the one in topic. On the topic, I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox and the result in console shows exactly 0. I return the values from backend as `echo json_encode(["type"=>0,"medium"=>0,"text"=>"Some text"]);`. I can not reproduce issue in order for offering further help.